# Eclipse progress view

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I develop an eclipse plugin and I added an eclipse progress view to it. There is an stop button on the progress view and I want to create some kind of listener to handle the events of the cancel button, but I don't know how I can do it. I know the monitor has an isCanceled() method, but I have to create come kind of listener to listen when user clicks the stop button, while the plugin works. Please give me some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do here is check the `isCanceled` method often while you are on your long-running code.  If `isCanceled` returns true, you return from your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

The progress view normally monitors `Job` objects; you extend `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` and implement `run()` to define a Job. That class has a `canceling()` method; you can override `canceling()` and set a flag to `true`. Then in your `run()` method, you just loop until that flag becomes `true` (or the work is done), at which point you cleanup and return.